# How can I list all files which have been installed by an APT package?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I have installed the package `geoip-bin` using the `apt-get` command:

```
sudo apt-get install geoip-bin
```

and I wanted to know the command line command to use this package.
But when I try to list the files that the `geoip-bin` package installs, to try and find the executable file, it's not listed in the `dpkg -S` output

```
% dpkg -S geoip-bin
geoip-bin: /usr/share/doc/geoip-bin/changelog.Debian.gz
geoip-bin: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/geoip-bin
geoip-bin: /usr/share/doc/geoip-bin
geoip-bin: /usr/share/doc/geoip-bin/copyright
```

After some research I learnt that this package installs a command/executable `/usr/bin/geoiplookup`. So at this point, I now know
the command, but for future purposes, I would like to know how to find out what files a package installs.

Doing a "reverse" file lookup with, `dpkg -S` shows that this file came from the `geo-ip` bin package.

```
% dpkg -S /usr/bin/geoiplookup
geoip-bin: /usr/bin/geoiplookup
```

I wondered if `dpkg -S` is not showing the file in the output because `/usr/bin/geoiplookup` is provided by one of the dependencies of `geoip-bin`.  After querying the dependencies with e.g. `apt-cache show geoip-bin` and then recursively querying the files and sub-dependencies, I still was not able to list the files provided by the package `geoip-bin`.
How can I generate a full listing of the files installed by a package?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

-L, --listfiles

```
dpkg -L package-name
```