# where does shared objects go after installing and how to find out their names

Tags: ubuntu, c, c++

I just installed the SFML library using the following command: `apt-get install sfml-dev`

and after installing it I went to my `/usr/lib` folder to find out what the actual shared object's name is (so that I know what to tell my compiler what to use).

But there was nothing with "SFML" in the name there.

There was, however, an SFML folder in my /usr/include directory.

So where are the shared object files, if they aren't in my `/usr/lib` directory?

How can I find them, so that I can figure out what to tell the compiler to use?

`g++ *.cpp -o exe -l`?

Comment: Possibly related: [How can I generate a complete list of files for a package installed with dpkg?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306872/how-can-i-generate-a-complete-list-of-files-for-a-package-installed-with-dpkg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gcc -print-search-dirs
```

shows all the search paths the compiler uses.

```
dpkg -L libsfml-dev
```

shows all the files installed by the package; to find the actual library though you’ll need to run `dpkg -L` on whichever package actually contains the library (`libsfml-dev` has a number of library dependencies).

In any case, libraries typically end up in `/usr/lib/$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)` nowadays on Debian derivatives, *i.e.* `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` on common 64-bit PCs. You don’t actually need to worry about that with your compiler though, it already knows where to find the libraries — you just need to figure out what `-l` parameters to provide it with.