# How to find commands associated to a package?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, command, dpkg

Sometimes I find myself installing a package and then trying to run a command using the same name, [like with `geoip-bin`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306872/209677) package:

```
$ sudo apt install geoip-bin
```

[...]

```
$ geoip-bin
geoip-bin: command not found
```

How may I find all the commands associated with a given package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `dpkg -L`

`-L, --listfiles package-name` List files installed to your system from *package-name*.

Two alternatives:

- [Usually works just](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394604/how-to-find-commands-associated-with-a-package/394605#comment704048_394605): `dpkg -L byobu | egrep '/bin/|/sbin/'` (or even with `grep bin` if you don't care getting some [false positives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives#False_positive_error)).
- Or

  ```
  dpkg -L byobu | xargs which
  ```
- Or with [some bash magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812324/finding-executable-files-using-ls-and-grep#comment61157685_7812393):

  ```bash
  for f in $(dpkg -L geoip-bin) ; do test -x $f -a ! -d $f && echo $f ; done
  ```

  Optionally you could add `| grep "/usr/bin/"` at the end to list executables files on that particular folder.

`geoiplookup` was the command of `geoip-bin`. I also found this very useful to learn about other commands of any package.

Comment: Not everything lives in `/usr/bin` though e.g. `mailman` hides commands under `/usr/lib/mailman/bin`

Comment: Sure, that's why I put _optionally_. I extended the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Shorter with just `dpkg -L package | grep '/bin/'`

Comment: @Kusalananda It's impossible for a package command to be in a directory that does not contain "/bin/" on it path?

Comment: @PabloBianchi No, but if you look at your `$PATH`, it mostly contains `/bin/` directories, right? You could change it to `bin/` to also catch any `sbin` commands.

Comment: Leve some paths out (`echo $PATH | tr : \\n | egrep -v "/sbin|/bin"`) but usually works, I added to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the command `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -S $(which <command>)
```

e,g:

```
$ dpkg -S $(which cp)
coreutils: /bin/cp
```

the command `cp` is a part of `coreutils` package.

To see all commands associated to `coreutils` package:

```
$dpkg -s coreutils

Specifically, this package includes:

 arch base64 basename cat chcon chgrp chmod chown chroot cksum comm cp
 csplit cut date dd df dir dircolors dirname du echo env expand expr
 factor false flock fmt fold groups head hostid id install join link ln
 logname ls md5sum mkdir mkfifo mknod mktemp mv nice nl nohup nproc numfmt
 od paste pathchk pinky pr printenv printf ptx pwd readlink realpath rm
 rmdir runcon sha*sum seq shred sleep sort split stat stty sum sync tac
 tail tee test timeout touch tr true truncate tsort tty uname unexpand
 uniq unlink users vdir wc who whoami yes
```

Comment: What I asked was the opposite. Not _getPackage(command)_ but _getCommands(package)_.

Comment: But that's particular to `coreutils` package, they decide to put that on _Description_ metadata field. Use `dpkg -s geoip-bin` (or `apt show`) and you won't get a list of available commands.

Comment: correct `dpkg -s` will not show all the available commands, `dlocate` should be the easy and the fast way (Gille and Terdon answer's)

Comment: dkpg -L  is not seeing the package `sleuthkit` i installed.  not sure how to list its commands.