# How can I list all files which will be installed by an APT package?

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, ubuntu, apt

This is similar to [How can I list all files which have been installed by an APT package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306872/how-can-i-generate-a-full-listing-of-the-files-installed-by-a-package) However, I want to know which files **will** be installed as the package has not been installed, yet.

**Example:** I wanted to list all files which will be installed by APT package `xorg`. In other words: all files which will possibly be created when I type `apt install xorg`. However, `apt-file` listed only the immediate files of `xorg` - not of its dependencies:

```
$ apt-file list xorg
xorg: /usr/share/bug/xorg/script
xorg: /usr/share/doc/xorg/changelog.gz
xorg: /usr/share/doc/xorg/copyright
xorg: /usr/share/lintian/overrides/xorg
```

How can I list **all** associated files?

(I will add an awful `bash` pipe combination as an answer. This is what I'm using right now, but its just a loop with many calls to `apt-file` and therefore very, very slow. I'm looking for a better answer.)

Answer (score 2):

You can feed `apt-file list` a list of packages to process in one go, using

```
apt-file -f-
```

(to read from standard input). My measurements suggest that

```
apt-get -s install xorg | awk '/^Inst / { print $2 }' | apt-file -f- list
```

is over twice as fast as the same process with an `apt-file` loop (using `xargs`).

I post-process that with `sort -k2,2` since I quite like to see the package involved.

Using `apt-get -s install` instead of post-processing `apt-cache depends xorg` means that all the packages which would be installed on your system are taken into account, and only those packages, including recursive dependencies. `apt-cache depends xorg` only shows `xorg`’s immediate dependencies and your post-processing doesn’t handle alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm using right now, but it might be buggy and is definitely not very performant:

```
apt-cache depends xorg | grep '..\(Depends\|Recommends\): [^<]' | sed 's/[^:]*: //' | while read LINE; do [[ -z "$LINE" ]] || apt-file list "$LINE"; done | sed 's/[^:]*: //' | sort
```

---

**Step-by-step:**

Get list of packages which will be installed:

```
apt-cache depends xorg
```

Select the "depends" and "recommends" entries:

```
grep '..\(Depends\|Recommends\): [^<]'
```

Strip everything except the package name:

```
sed 's/[^:]*: //'
```

If the line isn't empty, run `apt-file` with each package name:

```
while read LINE; do [[ -z "$LINE" ]] || apt-file list "$LINE"; done
```

`apt-file list` returns lines where each line begins with the corresponding package name for the file. Remove package name from line, which leaves only the filename:

```
sed 's/[^:]*: //'
```

Sort lines:

```
sort
```