# theharvester not found in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, command-not-found

I am running latest 64 bit kali linux in VirtualBox and I am not able to find the theharvester.py anywhere

even using locate i cannot find it

and it is installed as when i run the install command i get the following output

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install theharvester
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
theharvester is already the newest version (3.1-0kali2).
theharvester set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libayatana-ido3-0.4-0 libbfio1
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
```

and when i run theharvester command in terminal i get

```
root@kali:/usr/share# theharvester
bash: theharvester: command not found
```

Comment: Did you try [the suggestion I linked to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306872/how-can-i-list-all-files-which-have-been-installed-by-an-apt-package) in your (now deleted) SO question? It should give you a list of files installed in the apt package, which might help you find the one you need to run

Comment: Try `apropos harvester`. Also, `locate` will not necessarily find what you're looking for. For complete results, use `find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theHarvester contains an upper case H [(GitHub)](https://github.com/laramies/theHarvester/blob/master/theHarvester.py). As filenames are case sensitive on Linux / Kali run `theHarvester`.

In the past Kali modified the casing to use a lower case h. This was changed recently as can be seen at the git repository from Kalis theHarvester package [(theharvester!f2caac3e)](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/theharvester/commit/f2caac3e9a727a8785e09a39eb4277caa3ab6a61)

The documentation at has not been updated so far [(ref)](https://tools.kali.org/information-gathering/theharvester). I've opened an issue [theharvester#2](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/theharvester/issues/2). The name change was done because one of theHarvester core devs asked to get it fixed. [theharvester#1](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/theharvester/issues/1)

Answer (score 0):

I used `apt-file` to search for theharvester.py.
It says that it belongs to the package `golismero`. After install of this package it should be under `/usr/share/golismero/plugins/testing/recon/`.

Answer (score 0):

so you have to do is run the command
locate theHarvester

after that look for the directory with tools and then go for that
cd to that path /usr/lib/(whatever it says for you)
then do ls and find if theHarvester.py exist in it and you're good to go

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, please note that the actual problem is the wrong capitalization in the OP's attempt to run the program (which is related to a change in the distribution's naming convention), so your answer doesn't quite address the problem.