# How to find out where different packages are installed?

Tags: linux, debian, directory

While downloading different packages(For example, [Xbindkeys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys)) I was having difficulties finding the different files. How does one know which directories downloaded files are in? Is there a command to run? A package manager?

Comment: Based on the `debian` tag, `dpkg -L xbindkeys`. See for example [How can I list all files which have been installed by an APT package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306872/how-can-i-list-all-files-which-have-been-installed-by-an-apt-package)

Comment: Thank you, definitely take note. There is a file a tutorial said to create `.xbindkeysrc`. But it's not there

Comment: Dot-files are user configuration files, which aren’t shipped in packages (or only as examples). For `.xbindkeysrc`, look at `/usr/share/doc/xbindkeys/examples/xbindkeysrc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the name of the package, *e.g.* `xbindkeys`, you can list its contents in various ways:

- `dpkg -L xbindkeys` if it’s installed;
- `dpkg-deb -c xbindkeys_1.8.6-1+b1_amd64.deb` if you have the package file (without necessarily installing it);
- `apt-file list xbindkeys` whether or not it’s installed (if the indexes are up-to-date);
- [on the packages.debian.org site](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/xbindkeys/filelist).

You’re looking for `.xbindkeysrc`; that’s a user configuration file, so it won’t be listed as such in the package (because packages don’t touch home directory contents, apart from root’s). However many packages ship example configuration files, and you’ll find `/usr/share/doc/xbindkeys/examples/xbindkeysrc` in `xbindkeysrc`.