# How can I list all files which have been installed by the APT command

Tags: shell-script, command-line, find, package-management

I tried [How can I list all files which have been installed by an APT package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306872/how-can-i-list-all-files-which-have-been-installed-by-an-apt-package). But the problem is, for example:

when I run `sudo apt install libvirt-daemon-system` it does not only install one package (in this case `libvirt-daemon-system`). It also installs the packages mentioned under **The following NEW packages will be installed:**

```
$ sudo apt install libvirt-daemon-system
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cpu-checker ibverbs-providers ipxe-qemu ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms libcacard0 libfdt1 libibverbs1 libiscsi7 libpmem1 librados2 librbd1
  librdmacm1 libslirp0 libspice-server1 libusbredirparser1 libvirglrenderer1 libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu
  libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd libvirt-daemon-system-systemd libvirt0 msr-tools ovmf qemu-block-extra qemu-kvm qemu-system-common
  qemu-system-data qemu-system-gui qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils seabios
Suggested packages:
  libvirt-daemon-driver-lxc libvirt-daemon-driver-vbox libvirt-daemon-driver-xen libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-gluster
  libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-zfs numad auditd nfs-common open-iscsi radvd systemtap zfsutils samba vde2 debootstrap
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cpu-checker ibverbs-providers ipxe-qemu ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms libcacard0 libfdt1 libibverbs1 libiscsi7 libpmem1 librados2 librbd1
  librdmacm1 libslirp0 libspice-server1 libusbredirparser1 libvirglrenderer1 libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu
  libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-daemon-system-systemd libvirt0 msr-tools ovmf qemu-block-extra qemu-kvm
  qemu-system-common qemu-system-data qemu-system-gui qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils seabios
0 upgraded, 33 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 22.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 93.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

So, I am not getting the full picture by running `dpkg -L libvirt-daemon-system`

One option to get list of all the files that has been created after the `apt install` command can be to run

```
dpkg -L libvirt-daemon-system
dpkg -L cpu-checker
dpkg -L ibverbs-providers
dpkg -L ipxe-qemu
....
```

But I assume it will be a lengthy process.

Another option can be to run the following after installing the packages:

```
sudo find / -xdev -mtime -5 -type f ! -path '/home/blueray/*' ! -path '/timeshift/*'
```

Is there any better solution to get list of all the files that has been created after an `apt install` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the fact, you can feed the list of installed packages to `dpkg -L`:

```
dpkg -L libvirt-daemon-system cpu-checker ibverbs-providers ipxe-qemu \
        ipxe-qemu-256k-compat-efi-roms libcacard0 libfdt1 libibverbs1 \
        libiscsi7 libpmem1 librados2 librbd1 librdmacm1 libslirp0  \
        libspice-server1 libusbredirparser1 libvirglrenderer1 \
        libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu \
        libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd libvirt-daemon-system \
        libvirt-daemon-system-systemd libvirt0 msr-tools ovmf \
        qemu-block-extra qemu-kvm qemu-system-common qemu-system-data \
        qemu-system-gui qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils seabios
```

This won’t be lengthy in most cases (although the *result* can be, and is in this case).

With some preparation, you can list all the files installed by packages (excluding changes made by their maintainer scripts). Before you run `apt`, store the list of all the files that the packaging system knows about:

```
sort -u /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list > files-before
```

After you run `apt`, store it again, in a different file:

```
sort -u /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list > files-after
```

You can then compare the two files to see what changed, *e.g.* with

```
comm files-{before,after}
```

or

```
meld files-{before,after}
```

This will also work for package removals, and file removals during package upgrades; your `find` approach wouldn’t be able to determine what got removed.

In scenarios where you’re only interested in files installed by new (or upgraded) packages, you can look at the file lists modified in the last *x* minutes, *e.g.* 10:

```
find /var/lib/dpkg/info -name \*.list -mmin -10 -exec sort -u {} +
```

or, if you’re using Zsh:

```
sort -u /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list(mm-10)
```

Comment: In `zsh`, see also `sort -u /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list(mm-10)` for the lists last modified in the last 10 minutes (assuming `apt` was run less than 10 minutes ago and it was the only invocation in the interval).

Comment: Being lengthy is not a issue for me. I will grep it anyway. In this case I am doing `| grep bin/`